# Induced EMF confusion

Tags: electromagnetism

I have a somewhat general question. If I have two loops of conducting wire, and I pass current through one, is the induced emf on the other loop the same electromotive force that would have occurred in the first one if I passed the same current through the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is always *yes* independent of the numbers of turns, size, etc.  The mutual inductance coeffcients $M_{ij}$ are symmetric: $M_{12}=M_{21}$ *etc*.  This is known as the reciprocity relation. See the secition "Mutual inductance and magnetic field energy" in the Wikipedia article on "Inductance."

Answer (score 0):

Induced emf will only be same :

1. If the orientation of one loop with respect to the other one is same.
2. Number of turns in both loop are same.

However  the current (induced) will also be dependent on the material used, since resistance of material will differ.